# Python3 multiprocessing or multi thread for loop

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a big ML based package which has several modules (4) which read and write sequentially their own I/O. I also have several files (variable number). I understand the difference between thred and process but I m still puzzling of which one would make more sense to implement. A dummy structure is like this

```
import module1
import module2
import module3
import module4


for fl in list_of_files:
   tmp_path = os.path.join('tmp', fl) # here we create the folder which holds all tmp files
   module1.do_stuff(fl)
   module2.do_stuff(tmp_path) # input here is output of module1
   module3.do_stuff(tmp_path) # input is output of module2
   module4.do_stuff(tmp_path) # input here is output of module3
aggregate_results('tmp/') # this takes all outputs from module4 and combine them into a single file
```

Now my question is does it make sense to split it according to the files like this?

```
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp

def small_proc(fl):
     tmp_path = os.path.join('tmp', fl)
     module1.do_stuff(fl)
     module2.do_stuff(tmp_path)
     module3.do_stuff(tmp_path)
     module4.do_stuff(tmp_path)


p=mp.Pool(len(list_of_files)
p.map(single_file,list_of_files)
p.close()
p.join()
```

Or to split it according to the order of run as we can safely run the loop offset by one module (if that makes any sense to anybody?)

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: Yup It works but it has been running for a while, seems there is a lot of overhead. even thou a one of the module (3) takes approx 2hrs per file, so maybe at the end it is going to be an advantage in terms of time